# MobileFirst 8: protecting static resources

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

The scenario is: from within a MobileFirst hybrid app, I need to show PDFs that will be residing on the server. For security reasons, I wouldn't like to just protect them by HTTP authentication (in Apache that I use as a reverse proxy to TomCat running MobileFirst).

What would be the simplest way to protect static resources by MobileFirst 8 authentication? Can I just configure TomCat to utilize it or do I have to code anything in Java? Processing them all the way through adapters (incl. base64-encoding) looks unnecessarily complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your files in a "resources server". You can protect this server with a confidential client in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0.

Read more about this, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/confidential-clients/

But yes, this will require you to implement some code.